# OpenCL Atomic add for vector types?

Tags: vector, opencl, atomic

I'm updating a single element in a buffer from two lanes and need an atomic for float4 types. (More specifically, I launch twice as many threads as there are buffer elements, and each successive pair of threads updates the same element.)

For instance (this pseudocode does nothing useful, but hopefully illustrates my issue):

```
int idx = get_global_id(0);
int mapIdx = floor (idx / 2.0);

float4 toAdd;
// ...
if (idx % 2)
{
    toAdd = (float4)(0,1,0,1);
}
else
{
    toAdd = float3(1,0,1,0);
}

// avoid race condition here?
// I'd like to atomic_add(map[mapIdx],toAdd);
map[mapIdx] += toAdd;
```

In this example, `map[0]` should be incremented by `(1,1,1,1)`. `(0,1,0,1)` from thread 0, and `(1,0,1,0)` from thread 1.

Suggestions? I haven't found any reference to vector atomics in the CL documents. I suppose I could do this on each individual vector component separately:

```
atomic_add(map[mapIdx].x, toAdd.x);
atomic_add(map[mapIdx].y, toAdd.y);
atomic_add(map[mapIdx].z, toAdd.z);
atomic_add(map[mapIdx].w, toAdd.w);
```

... but that just feels like a bad idea. (And requires a cmpxchg hack since there are no float atomics.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could try using local memory like that:

```
__local float4 local_map[LOCAL_SIZE/2];

if(idx < LOCAL_SIZE/2) // More optimal would be to use work items together than every second (idx%2) as they work together in a warp/wavefront anyway, otherwise that may affect the performance
    local_map[mapIdx] = toAdd;
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
if(idx >= LOCAL_SIZE/2)
    local_map[mapIdx - LOCAL_SIZE/2] += toAdd;
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
```

What will be faster - atomics or local memory -  or possible (size of local memory may be too big) depends on actual kernel, so you will need to benchmark and choose the right solution.

**Update:**

Answering your question from comments - to write later back to global buffer do:

```
if(idx < LOCAL_SIZE/2)
    map[mapIdx] = local_map[mapIdx];
```

Or you can try without introducing local buffer and write directly into global buffer:

```
if(idx < LOCAL_SIZE/2)
    map[mapIdx] = toAdd;
barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE); // <- notice that now we use barrier related to global memory
if(idx >= LOCAL_SIZE/2)
    map[mapIdx - LOCAL_SIZE/2] += toAdd;
barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
```

Aside from that I can see now problem with indexes. To use the code from my answer the previous code should look like:

```
if(idx < LOCAL_SIZE/2)
{
    toAdd = (float4)(0,1,0,1);
}
else
{
    toAdd = (float4)(1,0,1,0);
}
```

If you need to use `id%2` though then all the code must follow this or you will have to do some index arithmetic so that the values go into right places in `map`.

Comment: ... okay, and then, after the last barrier, have one of the threads write the result back to global?

Comment: So, this really comes down to: `if (condtion) { do_it(); } else { do_it();}` (with a barrier in the middle.) Which would be completely ludicrous in any other scenario. BUT, it works.

Comment: @3Dave That's oversimplified. `condition` here "filters" what given group of work items is doing. Remember that `toAdd` is a private variable visible by given work item only. First `if` reads first half of them and `else` second half. A `barrier` is needed so that we don't have race condition issues. Internally, depending on the vendor, work items operate together in 32/64 work items groups called waveform/warp.

Comment: I'm familiar with the architecture - this is just a *little* counter-intuitive. But, I've implemented it and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand issue correctly I would do next.
Get rid of ifs by making array with offsets

```
float4[2] = {(1,0,1,0), (0,1,0,1)}
```

and use idx %2 as offset

move `map` into local memory and use `mem_fence(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE)` to make sure all threads in group synced.